# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for associated models not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have two models (`Company` and `User`) that have a `belongs_to/has_many` relationship.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :users_attributes
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

In my `CompaniesController` I want to create a new instance of `Company` along with a group of `Users`.

```
class Cms::CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        company = Company.new(company_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if company.save
                format.json { render json: company, status: :ok }
            else
                format.json { render json: company.errors.messages, status: :bad_request }
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def company_params
        params.require(:company).permit(
            :id, 
            :name, 
            users_attributes: [
                :id,
                :_destroy,
                :first_name,
                :last_name,
                :email
            ]
        )
    end
end
```

When I call `company.save`, I would expect a new instance of `Company` along with several new instances of `User` to be saved, depending on how many users I have in my params, however no users are persisted.

Here is a sample of what `company_params` looks like:

```
{"id"=>nil, "name"=>"ABC", "users_attributes"=>[{"first_name"=>"Foo", "last_name"=>"Bar", "email"=>"foo@bar.com"}]}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: At first glance you're code looks sound, but I'm curious to see what would happen if you removed `attr_accessor :users_attributes` from the `Company` model

Comment: I get `Unpermitted parameters: token, id, users_attributes` when calling `company = Company.new(company_params)` and the value of `company_params` is now just `{"name" => "ABC"}`. Interestingly enough though, if I insert a `binding.pry` right before that line and copy/paste the code to define `company_params`, calling `Company.new(company_params)` creates the company AND the users. That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: do you have devise gem for users model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Everything else should work.

--

`attr_accessor` creates `getter`/`setter` methods in your class.

It's mostly used for [virtual attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) (ones which aren't saved to the database). Your current setup is preventing you from being able to save the `users_attributes` param, thus your `users` are not saving.